# saga 2.0.8 and gqis 2.0.1 on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: qgis, saga

is it possible to have saga 2.0.8 and qgis 2.0.1 installed  on ubuntu 13.0 4at the same time?
I have the ubuntugis-repositoy activated and I got no problem with qgis and grass, but it seems impossible to install saga.

The problem is the libgdal1 library: during the qgis installation, libgdal1 **h** is installed too. But saga want the libgdal1 library and then the conflict.

Some idea or suggestions?

BTW: the same error occurs with the johanvdw repository (for the 2.1 version of saga).

Comment: Had the same problem, maybe there is a solution by symlinking libraries, but i haven't looked in it deeply.

Comment: i'm trying to compile saga from the source code.. maybe that's another chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. I'm currently fixing it. (recompiling saga against the same version of gdal).

[update]

Please test! Version 2.0.8 should work (you may want to remove my ppa first to make sure you don't get the 2.1.0 version. This one still works with the original gdal version in the distro and not the one in ubuntugis (which causes the error).

Comment: Yes, it works! I have now saga correctly installed. Some problem with some algorithms in qgis through sextante, but that's another story. Thanks!